# How to add images of buildings inside a map?

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2

I'm going to do a trip and I want to have a custom map on my website. My idea is to have a map similar to this one for example.

[image: Map with custom buildings]

So I need to add images (svg or jpg) to the base map. I want a clean base map, so I don't like using Google Maps for this, that's why I'm trying a more custom approach (apart from learning new things).

I know nothing about GIS yet, but as I developer I'm eager to learn. I've seen two options:

- With a gis editing program, import a base layer for the area of my trip, edit the layer and add those svgs images. Is it possible to do this with QGIS and how? I fear that it can take too much work.
- Use something like OpenLayers and add those building images as overlays. I wonder if I can position it well to hide what's behind (I think with the [position and positioning parameters](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html) it could work).

Which one do you think is a better alternative? Any other option? I can spend some time, but I want to go on the right direction.

Comment: Might work with png icons and qgis2web

Comment: you can use a point layer (with the building locations) and svg (qgis) or png, emf, tif icons for the symbology.